# ssh into AWS Batch jobs

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-batch

I would like to communicate with AWS Batch jobs from a local R process in the same way that Davis Vaughn demonstrated for EC2 at https://gist.github.com/DavisVaughan/865d95cf0101c24df27b37f4047dd2e5. The AWS Batch documentation describes how to set up a key pair and security group for batch jobs. However, I could not find detailed instructions about how to find the IP address of a job's instance or what user name I need. The IP address in particular is not available in the console when I run the job, and `aws batch describe-jobs --jobs` prints out an empty `"jobs": []` JSON string. Where do I find the information I need to ssh into a job's instance? (In my use case, I would prefer the IP address instead of the host name.)

Comment: You're linking to an example that has EC2 instances.  AWS Batch hides the deployment details.  If you want to follow the link then you'll need EC2's, not Batch.

Comment: So there’s no way to communicate between the local process and the jobs? Going through storage seems much slower than ssh or socket connections.

Comment: Does AWS Batch support a message queue capable of sending back and forth in-memory data?

Comment: Your code runs in a docker container on an instance, you don't have ssh access to it. You could try EFS (https://aws.amazon.com/efs/) to share a filesystem between jobs.

Comment: So here is where I am confused. Why exactly does the [user guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/batch_user.pdf) repeatedly mention SSH to connect to AWS Batch container instances?

Comment: I also noticed it is possible to supply an EC2 keypair when creating an AWS Batch computing environment.

Comment: And what about reverse tunneling? Is that possible?

Answer (score 3):

Posting here in case this helps someone. The instance should show up under "Running instances" in your ec2 console. You should be able to use the public ip address specified there. Make sure you configured your batch job to use your ec2 key pair and the correct user name (ec2-user for amazon linux 2). eg. ssh -i "your_keypair.pem" ec2-user@XX.XXX.XX.XXX.

Comment: Thanks! Any way to get that IP address from the AWS API? Would like to build automated tools that can ssh into Batch jobs behind the scenes.

Comment: You should be able to use the api. I am not overly familiar with it, but the cli command to get the ip addresses would be something like this:
```aws ec2 describe-instances \
--filters \
"Name=instance-state-name,Values=running" \
"Name=instance-id,Values=<instance-id>" \  
--query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[PrivateIpAddress, PublicIpAddress]' \
--output text```